# ESP32: add other configuration to Wifimanager's setup page

Tags: esp32, wifimanager

The available Wifimanagers (e.g. https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager) handle Wifi-Setup for the ESP32 nicely (build up a setup page and start a webserver so that the user can configure it easily). Did anyone add other setup information (not related to Wifi) to this page?

I'm building ESP32 sensors that push their data to a server. So I'd like the server address and username etc. to be configurable in the web-interface that is already there.

Also I will generate a public key on my ESP32 that needs to be copied to the server. I'd like to display that as well on the configuration page for the user.

One could hack the existing infrastructure of the WifiManager, but maybe someone could recommend a library that solves this problem.

Comment: Have you read [WiFiManager's documentation](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/blob/master/README.md)? Is there something you need that "custom parameters" and "custom HTML" aren't enough for?

Comment: Indeed I did not know that - I was satisfied with a tutorial and did not read the documentation in greater detail. Shame on me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't really blame you, a lot of these things have non-existent to incorrect documentation. I hope those features of the library work well for you.